# Dynamically insert a stylesheet in rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've build myself a real time theme picker for a CMS we're developing for school. The CMS is build with Ruby on Rails and I (personally) don't have any experience with Ruby on Rails (others are doing the backend stuff, I'm the frontend guy).

Now I want my theme picker, which is written in javascript (Backbone, Underscore and jQuery) to work with Rails, but I can't find out a right way to include the stylesheets in Rails. Currently I'm giving a static path:

```
// Insert a new stylesheet
var stylesheet = $("<link />", {
    href: "stylesheets/themes/theme-" + this.themeID + "/theme-color-" + colorset + ".css",
    rel: "stylesheet",
    id: "js-theme-colorset"
});

// Append the stylesheet to the iframe
$('head', $('#js-theme-iframe')[0].contentWindow.document ).append( stylesheet );
```

But the CMS is dynamic, so I want to grab the stylesheets out of the asset pipeline, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Tried this:

```
// Insert a new stylesheet
var stylesheet = '<%= stylesheet_link_tag "themes/theme-1/theme-color1.css", :id => "js-theme-colorset" %>';

// Append the stylesheet to the iframe
$('head', $('#js-theme-iframe')[0].contentWindow.document ).append( stylesheet );
```

But that didn't work out..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't it easier to throw your style in a cookie and reload the page?

Comment: "that didn't work out.." because what? You don't see content styled, css doesn't get appended? What?

Comment: @Ragnagord: That's a possibility.. The theme (HTML/CSS/JS) is put into a iFrame, but it's not a very nice solution. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @WTK: Because it was inserted as text or so. It wasn't executable, so the stylesheet wasn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, when you want to link to your stylesheet through javascript, you'll need to point to: assets.

The link I was looking for was: assets/themes/theme-0/theme-color-1.css

You don't need to specify stylesheets, Rails knows (apparently). Just link to the asset pipeline. Thanks for answers anyway :)!